# set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, phpseclib

I have stumbled upon two functions i have never used before in php

```
set_include_path();
get_include_path();
```

I am currently looking to implement the phpseclib onto a project I am working on.. As i need to use the SFTP class extension of the SSH2 which in turn requires the MathBigInteger class.. etc etc.

The manual says about `set_include_path()`:

> "Sets the include_path configuration option for the duration of the
>   script. "

What does this mean for the rest of my framework, will it set ALL include paths from the 'phpseclib' dir?

Also, I really don't get:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
```

I am storing the php sec in a custom library directory in my file system, does get_include_path() some how magically find the phpseclib directory in my filesystem?

As you can see I am completely lost here.. could anyone be kind enough to shed some light for me please?

PS/
I only need this library at one partivular point in the application thus only want to include it when needed, at present I am wanting to include it within a child of my model class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what the [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) configuration setting does:

> Specifies a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(),
>   file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files.
>   The format is like the system's PATH environment variable: a list of
>   directories separated with a colon in Unix or semicolon in Windows.
>
> PHP considers each entry in the include path separately when looking
>   for files to include. It will check the first path, and if it doesn't
>   find it, check the next path, until it either locates the included
>   file or returns with a warning or an error. You may modify or set your
>   include path at runtime using set_include_path().

The construct

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
```

appends `phpseclib` to the list of directories searched when you request including a file with one of the above functions.

Since `phpseclib` is a relative path, the effect is the same as if you had specified `./phpseclib`, i.e. PHP will look into a subdirectory named `phpseclib` inside the current directory of the process. It does not magically determine where the library is located in the filesystem; it's your job to put it where it will be found.

Comment: thank you, this was a completely new concept to me, but makes much more sense now

Answer (score 6):

To better understand what `include_path` is and isn't, read [this section](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) of php.ini manual.

If you're trying to write a project-specific "autoloader", `set_include_path` is not the best tool for that (you might want to look into [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead), but to answer your question:

`set_include_path` does overwrite whatever previous `include_path` was. Multiple paths can be provided using `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant as a separator, eg:

```
set_include_path($path1. PATH_SEPARATOR . $path2 . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path3);
```

thus you can add to already existing path instead of overwriting it like this:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $mypath);
```

Comment: Thank you. Php... never ending!

Answer (score 1):

The the set_include_path just sets a possible location for the PHP engine to look for files.  For example:

```
set_include_path( WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'scripts\phpseclib' );
if(include('Net/SSH2.php')){
    echo 'pass';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
include WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'application/global_function_list.php';
```

The above worked perfectly well and continues to include correctly other files required for the application.

Answer (score 0):

John, I think the reason your second example fails is that 'phpseclib' doesn't specify a full path.  Assuming your first example works, you would want to replace

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
```

with

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'scripts\phpseclib');
```

in the second example.  To confirm that your include_path is what you think it should be, you might add the line

```
echo get_include_path() . " is my include path.\n";
```

right after the set_include_path() call.